# Finding $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac {\sin^2z}{e^z-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $$g(z)= \frac{z \sin^2z}{e^z -1}$$
and Let $$f(z)=\begin{cases}
g(z) &z \neq 0 \\ 
 0&   z=0
\end{cases}$$

It's obvious that f is continuous at 0 .

Is f is analytic at 0 ?

This amounts to showing that:

$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac {\sin^2z}{e^z-1}$$
exists.

Comment: Note: the function in the title is not the same as the function in the post.  Which is the one you're interested in?

Comment: I need to find the limit in the title to check analycity at o.

Comment: @Glitch The question is about whether $g(z)/z$ converges as $z\to 0$.

Answer (score 9):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{\sin^2 z}{e^z-1}=\frac{\sin z \frac{\sin z}{z}}{\frac{e^z-1}{z}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\sin z = z+O(z^3)$
and 
$e^z =1+z+O(z^2)$
which gives the desired result.